# Templates :: Stroustrup's example is not compiling

Tags: c++, templates, stl

"No matching member function push_back"

In Bjarne's original version vector of C was written like

`vector<Value_type<C>*> res;`

but this Value_type template is not working as well
so I just replaced it with C* pointer, still doesn't help

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename C, typename V>
vector<C*> find_all(C& c, V v) {
    vector<C*> res;
    for (auto &x : c) {
        if (x==v)
            res.push_back(&x);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    string s = "werqewreqwreqw";
    for (const auto p : find_all(s,'q')) {
        cout << p;
    }

}
```

Comment: The real problem is why the first version didn't work. Where is `Value_type` defined? I'm not as familiar with Bjarne's book code. Edit: [found it](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h). Are you compiling with C++11 and a compiler that supports the `using` syntax?

Comment: @chris I've got it from video lecture slides and unfortunatelly, no other code is given... but why we need value_type. isn't it simpler just to define C* pointer (as we define vector of pointers to C' element)

Comment: They're not the same. Yours is a vector of pointers to instances of the container type and the original is a vector of pointers to instances of the element type.

Comment: the simplest change is to change the result type to vector<V*>, and the output to *p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C*` is not the same as `C::value_type*`. Actually, there's already a typedef that represents the same concept, which is `C::pointer`.

```
template <typename C, typename V>
vector<typename C::pointer> find_all(C& c, V v) {
    vector<typename C::pointer> res;
```

FYI, `C::pointer` will be `std::allocator_traits<T>::pointer`, which is furthermore just `T*` for the default allocator or `value_type*`. I'm not entirely sure why `Value_type` was used but I'm assuming it was Bjarne's idea for a meta function that replaces `typename C::value_type`.

Comment: My guess is that `Value_type` is easier to teach because there's no `typename` (something that's irrelevant at that point in the course). As for `Value_type` vs. `Pointer`, I'd hazard a guess that `Value_type` is used elsewhere and it's not worth having both used for such a small benefit. Or that `Value_type<C>*` reads a bit better than `Pointer<C>`. The second, to me, doesn't read like "pointer to the element type of C".

Comment: cool, now it makes sense. What will happen if this C::value_type name will get referred to containertype with not defined "value_type"?  Obviously it won't compile. but how to make really universal find_all template? i.e for char* strings we don't need value_type we can return pointer to char , etc..

Comment: @chris Realistically, it was probably to save [space on the slide](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~aho/cs4115/lectures/14-01-29_Stroustrup.pdf) (page 29)

Comment: @barney Well it's not a container unless it meets the container requirements. There's no need to re-write "find_all" when something similar exists in `<algorithm>`.